# How to convert addresses shown by IDA when statically analyzing a DLL to real addresses in runtime

Tags: ida, windows, dll, pointer, msvc

In a DLL I am trying to reverse there often is a reference to something I believe to be a fixed pointer (like a global var) which looks like dword_10038534. The references I am talking about look like this

```
v7 = dword_10038534
v10 = v7
v4 = (*(int (__thiscall **)(int, int))(*(_DWORD *)v10 + 44))(v10, a2);
```

1. Am I right to assume this is a pointer?
2. I would also assume that address is valid within the address space of the DLL module and will change when the DLL is loaded? So how do I calculate the actual run-time address if I load the DLL into my (c++) application?
3. As you might've noticed, the code I've shown looks like a function call and the function resides at given address. Is there any way to find the actual function body? I am not sure about this, but the functions might be dynamically loaded from another DLL (not through import but rather loadModule & getProcAddress). I managed to find some places where this object (situated at dword_10038534) is constructed, like there are values put at addresses relative to it, however I cannot figure out how the functions are loaded.

For context this DLL was created in late 90s using Visual c++ (most likely VC++4). There is no anti-debug or packing in place. I have heard that patterns like the one I've shown may be connected with C++ classes and virtual method table, however I have strong reasons to believe the DLL was written in C not C++, although this is unconfirmed

Comment: The following article itself as well as linked articles may be of interest for you: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170120-00/?p=95225